# Multiple lines in edittext changes the layout

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

I am developing my first application in android. My xml layout file has relativelayout and linearlayout both. My root layout is relative layout which has textviews, buttons and edittext and 2 more relativelayouts in it. In my 1st relativelayout i have an edittext below it i have button and switch. when i enter data more than 1 line in the edittext my button and switch below it overlaps.

How can i let my edittext to accept more than 1 line without changing the layout of the widgets below it ?

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/relative1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/blue3"  >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Name"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/taskname"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView7" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/taskname"
    android:hint="@string/hint_name"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView7">
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Set Location"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/taskname"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView7" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set"
    android:src="@drawable/pin1"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:onClick="set_loc"
    style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/taskname"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relative3" />



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Always alert me"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button5" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relative2"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/taskname">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pickDate"
        android:src="@drawable/c2"
        style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
        android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pickTime"
        style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
        android:src="@drawable/c1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relative3"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Add Task"
        android:onClick="add_task"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:onClick="cancel"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginStart="37dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You want the Edittext to change in size dynamically without it affecting the layout of other elements on screen? is that your question?

Comment: @JohnWhite Yess.. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is possible. To do so, you need to keep in mind what you are using - `RelativeLayout`. RelativeLayout lays out each item in relation to other elements on screen. So, if you have elements whose layout is dependent on the EditText, their position will change if the dimensions of the edit text are changed.

So that being said, you need to go through your layout and remove all layout references to the edit text, and rebuild your layout with that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the xml of Switch if you want switch below button..

```
android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
```

As an alternatice, you can view the design and as you are using relativelayout, just hardcoded the string of two lines in XML view and than drag and drop the resources as per need.